# Multiples has_many association with the same table ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to have in each User two references to the Caregivers table, the relationship would be bidirectional has_many, the problem is that I must have something wrong in the definitions because when I have a User in the variable current_user and I execute the following lines in a controller: current_user .reported_caregivers << @caregiver, current_user.save, nothing is saved.

These are the models:

```
class Caregiver < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :users, dependent: :nullify #first reference to User
   has_many :reporters, :class_name => 'User', dependent: :nullify #new reference
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :caregivers, dependent: :nullify #first reference
   has_many :reported_caregivers, :class_name => 'Caregiver', dependent: :nullify #new reference
...
```

And these are the migrations

```
class AddReportersToCaregivers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
   def change
     add_reference :caregivers, :reporters, foreign_key: { to_table: :users}, default: []
   end
end

class AddReportedCaregiversToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
   def change
     add_reference :users, :reported_caregivers, foreign_key: { to_table: :caregivers}, default: []
   end
end
```

Comment: Isn't a caregiver or a reporter a user too? And what is the relationship between them, does a user always have exactly one caregiver or multiple? One reporter or many? Are caregiver only work for one user? Can a reporter report multiple users? Would you mind elaborating on the associations between those models.

Comment: how about a join table that also specifies the role(s). 

User <--> CaregiverUser <--> Caregiver

CaregiverUser: id, user_id, caregiver_id, role

then role can be a String (or number or FK to another table or whatever you need to distinguish the different roles)

Answer (score 1):

There is no use of bidirectional has_many association of activerecord. If User table has_many caregivers, then Caregiver table should be `belongs_to :user`.

If you want each table to have many of other records, then you should consider to use `has_and_belongs_to_many` association. Only way to use has_many relation to both way is using `:through`, but you need another table for it. You can learn more about the associations [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).